# Automating custom reports - is LaTeX the right solution for me?

Tags: xetex, pdftex, signatures

I need to generate nice-looking PDF contracts and custom reports from the command-line, and I'm trying to determine whether LaTeX (XeLaTeX specifically, based on my research over the last few days) is the best solution for this, or whether I would save more time and have more freedom to customise things by simply using one of the many CLI tools that will convert a DOCX or a HTML file to PDF.

For the contract, it seems very few such templates for LaTeX exist out there, but I have come across [this nice-looking template](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/contract) that looks like it could be modified for my needs - but I'm unsure how well it will work in XeLaTeX.

For the PDF custom reports, they will need to:

- Contain custom fonts, logos and electronically-signable signatures
- Have Owner and User passwords set for encrypted security
- Be as customisable as possible (things like fine-tuning the placement of logos)
- Have the output of other command-line tools and programs dynamically inserted into them (XeLaTeX will be the final step in a whole automation process that starts with running other CLI tools)

Is XeLaTeX a good idea for me, or would it be less customisable, less efficient or otherwise  unsuitable compared to the solutions mentioned above? Thanks in advance, I'd appreciate some help from the automation experts here.

Comment: If you don't know LaTeX yet, I doubt, that you will save a lot of time. It certainly checks all you boxes, except encryption (you will need to use something like [pdftk](https://gitlab.com/pdftk-java/pdftk) for that). Maybe you should consider [pandoc](https://pandoc.org) with [weasyprint](https://weasyprint.org/samples/) or [speedata](https://www.speedata.de/en/)

Comment: @DG' Thank you for the input, that makes a lot of sense. To clarify, if I was converting from HTML to PDF (.i.e no DOCX), would I still need `pandoc`, or would `weasyprint` be sufficient?

Comment: From HTML you can go directly to `weasyprint`; have a look at the tutorial: https://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @DG' And conversely, if I had a DOCX, I'm guessing `weasyprint` would not be necessary because I could just use `pandoc` to do DOCX to PDF?

Comment: Well, if you are using pandoc, you need some kind of pdf-engine. That can be i.e.  `xelatex`, `context`, or `weasyprint`. Check the full list here: https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--pdf-engine